# local variable cannot be resolved when declared inside loops, but when declared outside throws NPE

Tags: nullpointerexception, declaration

Basically what I'm doing is a patience test through a deck of cards to determine the probability of patience running out and the main method only prints out this number, with no user system input. When the first card is drawn, you say "1", second card you say "2", third card "3", and then you start over at the fourth card. So it's 1-2-3-1-2-3-1-... If you draw an ace when you say 1, a 2 when you say 2 or a 3 when you say 3, then the patience runs out. This is run through a 52-piece deck of cards a total of 100 times (maybe I'll set it to 1000). Below are implementations of two classes Card (creates card) and Carddeck (creates deck of cards) along with the main method d84.

```
public class Card {
public static final int SPADES = 1;
public static final int HEARTS = SPADES + 1;
public static final int DIAMONDS = SPADES + 2;
public static final int CLUBS = SPADES + 3;
private int rank;   // value
private int suit;   // color

/** Creates a card with color, suit (SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS) 
    and value, rank (1-13) */
public Card(int suit, int rank) {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;
}

/** Gets suit */
public int getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

/** Gets rank */
public int getRank() {
    return rank;
}

/** Returns a readable representation of the card, e.g. "diamonds jack" */
public String toString(){
    String suitString = "";     
    switch(suit) {
        case SPADES: suitString = "spades"; break;
        case HEARTS: suitString = "hearts"; break;
        case DIAMONDS: suitString = "diamonds"; break;
        case CLUBS: suitString = "clubs"; break;
    }
    String rankString = "";
    switch(rank) {
        case 1: rankString = "ace"; break;
        case 11: rankString = "jack"; break;
        case 12: rankString = "queen"; break;
        case 13: rankString = "king"; break;
        default: rankString = String.valueOf(rank);
    }
    return suitString + " " + rankString;
}
}
```

-

```
import java.util.Random;
public class CardDeck {
private Card[] theCards;
private int cardNbr = -1;
public CardDeck() {
    theCards = new Card[52];
    for (int suit = Card.SPADES; suit <= Card.CLUBS; suit++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < 13; r++) {
            theCards[r*suit] = new Card(suit, r+1);
        }
    }
}
public void shuffle() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        int n = rand.nextInt(52);
        theCards[i] = theCards[n];
    }
}
public boolean moreCards() {
    return cardNbr < 51;
}
public Card getCard() {
    cardNbr++;
    return theCards[cardNbr];
}}
```

-

```
public class d84 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int patBroke = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++){
        CardDeck deck = new CardDeck();
        deck.shuffle();
        while (deck.moreCards() == true) {
            int say = 1;
            while (say <= 3) {
                Card drawn = deck.getCard();
                if (say == drawn.getRank()) {
                    patBroke++;
                    break;
                }
            say++;
            }
            if (say == drawn.getRank()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("The probability of patience running out is " + (1-patBroke/100));
}
}
```

When executed, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: drawn cannot be resolved at d84.main(d84.java:17). It's declared? When this clause is removed the compiler states the same error at d84.java:11. If Card drawn is declared outside loop, then execution throws NullPointerException at 17 or 11.

The class Card is given in lecture so I'm not gonna change any code there. Carddeck on the other hand is my own implementation and the main method d84 is also my own code.

So, how do I avoid 'drawn cannot be resolved' and NPE in this case?

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: That's not an exception, that's a compiler error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with loops per se, but rather with the scope of variables within `{}` clauses.  A variable cannot be referenced outside of the scope within which it's declared.

Change your logic to:

```
        int say = 1;
        Card drawn = null;  // Added
        while (say <= 3) {
            drawn = deck.getCard();  // Changed
            if (say == drawn.getRank()) {
                patBroke++;
                break;
            }
            say++;
        }
        if (say == drawn.getRank()) {
            break;
        }
```

(But there are very likely other problems.)

Comment: Card drawn = null; is basically the same thing as Card drawn; or am I wrong? Anyhow I get NPE thrown at the drawn.getRank() rows. I'm not asking for anyone to scrutinize my called class methods but I don't get the NPE. Thanks btw.

Comment: @Christian - You have to say `Card drawn = null;` since `drawn` is otherwise only set inside the loop body, and the loop body is not (so far as the compiler can tell) guaranteed to be executed.  There must be a guaranteed setting of `drawn` between it's declaration and the use in that final `if`.